# Are villagers the only mobs you can interact with?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Are there any mobs in Minecraft, other than villagers, who exist for a reason other than to be slain by the player?

Comment: Would someone please explain why this is being voted down?

Comment: Creepers love a nice conversation but you have to get very close

Comment: Because the question is unclear? Either you made it silly on purpose, which made it unclear, or it's just not well written. You can't talk to villagers in the first place, so what are you looking for? Are you looking for other human-like mobs? Are you asking if there are more villages? Are you asking where the other real-life human players are? What problem are you trying to solve? We can't solve "lonely" for you, so you need to reword your question to be about something we can solve.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I was hoping to find mobs that you could interact with. I want to close this though because so many people have destroyed it.

Comment: Try "Are villagers the only mob you can interact with socially?" You can always fix a question, and then people can change their votes on it.

Comment: I reworded the question. I feel for @Young Guilo who seems to be learning how to use our website by making every mistake in the book.

Comment: @YoungGuilo if you havent, I strongly advise you read our FAQ thoroughly, it should help you avoid future mishaps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list of minecraft Mobs is [maintained here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mobs).

Currently there are:

**Passive**

- Bat
- Chicken
- Cow
- Mooshroom
- Ocelot
- Pig
- Sheep
- Squid
- Villager

**Neutral**

- Enderman
- Wolf
- Zombie Pigman

**Tamable**

- Wolf (Dog)
- Ocelot (Cat)

**Hostile**

- Blaze
- Cave Spider
- Creeper
- Ghast
- Magma Cube
- Silverfish
- Skeleton
- Slime
- Spider
- Spider Jockey
- Witch
- Wither Skeleton
- Zombie
- Zombie Villager

**EDIT:**

*Some Possible Non-Hostile, Non-Farming Interactions:*

- Wolf - can be tamed using Bones
- Ocelot - can be tamed using fish
- Sheep - Cut the grass
- Zombie Pigman - play tag (though they tend to take this the wrong way)
- Squid - synchronized swimming
- Ghast - Nether baseball (they always pitch)

Comment: Endermen are excellent conversational partners. "VWHHT VWHUD!"